# cygwin file path tab completion not working

Tags: bash, cygwin

How can I set up Cygwin to have tab completion?

Actually, I do have it automatically, but it does not seem to complete paths. How do I set it up to complete paths?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cygwin paths typically start with `/cygdrive/c` (substitute whatever drive letter you happen to be using, of course).  So to complete `c:\Program Files`, you must type (for instance) <kbd>/cygdrive/c/Prog</kbd> and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Also, note that Cygwin is case-sensitive, so `/cygdrive/c/prog` would not complete to `c:\Program Files` due to the lowercase 'p'.

Comment: Ahhhhh it was the case sensitivity thing all along :)

Comment: Yes, that's difficult to get used to with Cygwin.

Comment: For case insensitivity, add `set completion-ignore-case on` to your `~/.inputrc`

Comment: But Cygwin's "root" directory is the directory where you installed it. For example, my Cygwin home directory is both `/cygdrive/c/home/myname` and `/home/myname`

Comment: The default installation no longer contains the bash autocomplete module, so there is no autocomplete at all, unless you explicitly install it. (See cowlinator's answer below.)

Answer (score 12):

I'm answering this question because the answer seems to have changed since the previous accepted answer.
I just installed Cygwin, and found that the bash completion is in fact a distinct and separate installation module, "bash-completion".  It is not selected in the default installation, so you need to install/update it explicitly.

[image: bash-completion as distinct installation module]

Answer (score 3):

It's not cygwin per se that "has" tab completion; it's the *shell* you're using. By default, the cygwin shell is bash, which does indeed provide basic tab completion for executables on your path and files in the current directory. Does it not work for you?

Comment: As a quick test, if you type whoam at your bash prompt and press TAB, does it complete to whoami.exe?  It should, without any additional configuration on your part.

Comment: interesting! I does complete.. then maybe it just doesn't complete paths.. I've tried that for sure. any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is just an environment; the program you're interacting with is called the shell. There are many shells - bash, zsh, and others.

For bash, I've found [this set of instructions](http://hem.bredband.net/richardc/Cygwin.html) to modify your .inputrc file.

Comment: I guess I'm bash, since I read that's the default. In the instructions you specify it says it should be working automatically. and it doesn't. it mentions changing specific details at $HOME/.inputrc which I checked and I just don't have that file there. have any ideas? should I just find a file like that somewhere on the internet and place it there?
thanks!

Comment: Hi Michelle, you should create an empty file and add commands to it as instructed. When there is no such file in your home directory, default settings are used. You will find that this is a common pattern in UNIX -- using hidden (starting with .) configuration files placed in your home dir.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I install Cygwin on a new system, I have trouble getting tab completion to work the way I want it to, which is to *scroll* through the completion results with each TAB stroke rather than listing potential results and requiring that I continue until typing until finding a unique one that will actually complete with a TAB press.

The way to get it to scroll through valid results is to place the following command string in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
bind TAB:menu-complete
```